# infinite Cartesian products

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Quote from Wikipedia, [infinite set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_set):

> The Cartesian product of an infinite number of sets each containing at least two elements is either empty or infinite.

I know that this is the regime where we need AC, but before that, ...

How can I prove the quoted statement above?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the axiom of choice to prove this statement. You need the axiom of choice to prove that the product is non-empty, but here you allow for that possibility.

Let $\{P_i\mid i\in I\}$ be an infinite family of sets with at least two elements each. If $\prod P_i$ is empty we're done, if not there is at least one $F$ in the product. Define a function from the product onto $I$ as follows:

Let $f$ be in the product, if $f$ and $F$ differ on exactly one coordinate, $i$, then map $f$ to $i$. Otherwise map $f$ to some fixed $i_0\in I$.

You can show now that this function is surjective. And since $I$ is infinite, the product must be infinite too (since the image of a finite set is finite).

Comment: Can we prove $\mathbb R$ injects into the product, or that the product surjects onto $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Pretty sure that no on the first, the second is a close maybe. Here's an example to consider. Suppose $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, and $I$ has a Dedekind-finite power set (e.g. $I$ is amorphous), and $P_i=\{i,0\}$. Then the product should be more or less $2^I$, so certainly $\Bbb R$ does not inject into $2^I$. But if I recall some nice result by Halbeisen-Shelah, if $2^X$ can be mapped onto $\omega$ then it can be mapped onto $\Bbb R$. And I think this is sort of a typical case here, that you can find some power set in the product.

Comment: I do not recall that result... (Kuratowski proved that $X$ surjects onto $\omega$ iff $\omega$ injects into $\mathcal P(X)$ iff $\mathcal P(\omega)$ injects into $\mathcal P(X)$.)

Comment: Ah, I was slightly misremembering. If $\aleph_0\leq 2^X$ then $2^{\aleph_0}\leq 2^X$. It's Fact 8.1 in "Relations between cardinals" of Halbeisen-Shelah. They give two references, but also a combinatorial proof. So now I'm thinking that maybe it's possible that the product is not surjectible onto $\Bbb R$.